# Using a subquery in an sum(IF) statement

Tags: mysql

I am creating a pipeline report so we can count opportunities that have been added each week.

My query is:

```
    SELECT 
    sum(IF(o.date_entered > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 1,0))
```

Pretty simple and works. The problem is, sales now also wants to count any opportunity as new that has been moved out of a loss status. So, I left-joined to an audit table to include this use case. But now, it counts every instance of the audit table for a given account where the field = sales_stage and the before_value is a loss status. So, and not that this would happen that often if ever, but if an opportunity moves from loss to lead, back to loss, and back to lead, it will count it as 2 new opportunities. I just want to get the latest instance of field=sales_stage and before_value is a loss status, and count that one time.

I want something like a sub-query in the left join, and I keep trying to use MAX, but nothing's working. Here's part of my join:

```
    INNER JOIN opportunities o ON ao.opportunity_id=o.id
    LEFT JOIN opportunities_audit oa ON o.id=oa.parent_id 
                AND after_value_string = 'Loss'
                AND date_created > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Does anybody know the solution to this type of problem? Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: So you are expecting to get recent values for loss or something like this? A sample output would be better.

Comment: show us db schema, sample data and expected result Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.